# SplashScreen not stretched

Tags: android, xml

I want to implement a splash screen for my app, i'm using this code to show the image, but the image is centered and not stretched to the whole screen. How can i solve that problem?
Thank you very much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash"
         android:id="@+id/splash"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the android:windowBackground attribute as the style for the Activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/splash" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/splash"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Where `android:scaleType="fitXY"`is responsible for stretching the image.

Comment: Great ;), Have to add so "fitXY" attribute ;)! Thank you very much. Will accept the answer after 10 minutes :).